# Scale image through CSS

Tags: css

Dimensioned my body with width: 600px and height 400px. Through CSS Grid I managed to create this grid (see [this Codenpen](https://codepen.io/dsfcxv/pen/gOWBqRK)). I intend each square has the same dimension, on width and height. I gotten div "container" has the same dimensions of the body. But the remaining divs overlap this dimensions (parent div "container", the "father").

I must scale all images with the same dimensions or through css I can solve this issue?

I still can't understand this point. On CSS, here we should dimension to all screen with various scales and dimensions, but how I should think and organize my images to all layout fit into each other?
If you could share any book or article where I can understand this skill, I will appreciate very much.

**Note**: On the codepen I can't have the same problem as I have in the browser. I am a newbie guy!
Thanks

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three four" "five six seven eight" "nine ten eleven twelve";
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-area: one;
  background-color: green;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-area: two;
  background-color: rgb(25, 86, 199);
}

.item-3 {
  grid-area: three;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-area: four;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-5 {
  grid-area: five;
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
}

.item-6 {
  grid-area: six;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-7 {
  grid-area: seven;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-8 {
  grid-area: eight;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-9 {
  grid-area: nine;
  background-color: rgb(228, 11, 163);
}

.item-10 {
  grid-area: ten;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-11 {
  grid-area: eleven;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-12 {
  grid-area: twelve;
  background-color: blue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Grid-Template-Areas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box item-1">
      <img src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/protocol/img/logos/firefox/logo-lg-high-res.7ba3ce88e665.png" alt="image firefox">
    </div>
    <div class="box item-2"></div>
    <div class="box item-3"></div>
    <div class="box item-4"></div>
    <div class="box item-5">
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/red-apple-with-leaf-picture-id683494078?k=6&m=683494078&s=612x612&w=0&h=aVyDhOiTwUZI0NeF_ysdLZkSvDD4JxaJMdWSx2p3pp4=" alt="image apple">
    </div>
    <div class="box item-6"></div>
    <div class="box item-7"></div>
    <div class="box item-8"></div>
    <div class="box item-9">
      <img src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/protocol/img/logos/firefox/logo-lg-high-res.7ba3ce88e665.png" alt="image firefox">
    </div>
    <div class="box item-10">
      <img src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/protocol/img/logos/firefox/logo-lg-high-res.7ba3ce88e665.png" alt="image firefox">
    </div>
    <div class="box item-11"></div>
    <div class="box item-12">
      <img src="https://logosmarcas.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Apple-Logo-1977-1998.jpg" alt="image apple">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add the code so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I shared the all code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're defining body width and height to fixed size, so it will not resize in different screen sizes, because it's not inside a media query, you're plainly defining body width and height regardless of clients device, on all devices your site will be 600px * 400px

```
body {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

if you change it to % or Vh/Vw, it'll adjust to screen size automatically, it's a quick and dirty fix you can try it out, if you don't want this to happen. you have to use `@media` queries to scale according to screen sizes [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two three four"
    "five six seven eight"
    "nine ten eleven twelve";
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-area: one;
  background-color: green;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-area: two;
  background-color: rgb(25, 86, 199);
}

.item-3 {
  grid-area: three;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-area: four;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-5 {
  grid-area: five;
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
}

.item-6 {
  grid-area: six;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-7 {
  grid-area: seven;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-8 {
  grid-area: eight;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-9 {
  grid-area: nine;
  background-color: rgb(228, 11, 163);
}

.item-10 {
  grid-area: ten;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-11 {
  grid-area: eleven;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-12 {
  grid-area: twelve;
  background-color: blue;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box item-1">
    <img src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/protocol/img/logos/firefox/logo-lg-high-res.7ba3ce88e665.png" alt="image firefox">
  </div>
  <div class="box item-2"></div>
  <div class="box item-3"></div>
  <div class="box item-4"></div>
  <div class="box item-5">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/red-apple-with-leaf-picture-id683494078?k=6&m=683494078&s=612x612&w=0&h=aVyDhOiTwUZI0NeF_ysdLZkSvDD4JxaJMdWSx2p3pp4=" alt="image apple">
  </div>
  <div class="box item-6"></div>
  <div class="box item-7"></div>
  <div class="box item-8"></div>
  <div class="box item-9">
    <img src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/protocol/img/logos/firefox/logo-lg-high-res.7ba3ce88e665.png" alt="image firefox">
  </div>
  <div class="box item-10">
    <img src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/protocol/img/logos/firefox/logo-lg-high-res.7ba3ce88e665.png" alt="image firefox">
  </div>
  <div class="box item-11"></div>
  <div class="box item-12">
    <img src="https://logosmarcas.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Apple-Logo-1977-1998.jpg" alt="image apple">
  </div>
</div>
```